# url parameters in Command Line

Tags: php, command-line, compiler-construction, wkhtmltopdf

i am trying to make a pdf file with wkhtmltopdf when i pass url www.example.com pdf is generating or www.example.com?id=1

but when i try to put another parameter command execution is not working

www.example.com?id=1&type=u

> shell_exec("c:\pdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe
>   http://localhost/test/index.php?id=1&typee=abc
>   test.pdf ");

i try to use it via command line to but its not working there also

thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&` is causing your command to fail as it has special meaning in shell. Use [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to escape those characters first.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to escape parameters before passing them to the command line.

This is also mandatory when passing external data (e.g. user input) as parameters.